# how to filter between two existing date django

Tags: python, mysql, django

i'm trying to filter and check if two dates are already exists , for example we have this existing two dates `28-6-2021 11:30 PM` and `30-6-2021 11:30 PM` , i have to prevent the users to select any dates which contains between that two existing dates for example if the user try to select `29-6-2021 12:00 PM` to `1-7-2021 12:00 PM` it should raise an error `the dates already taken` !
this is my models.py

```
class Booking(models.Model):
    room_no = models.ForeignKey(Room,on_delete=models.CASCADE,blank=True,related_name='rooms')
    check_in = models.DateTimeField(default=datetime.now)
    check_out = models.DateTimeField()   

#my form

class BookingForm(forms.ModelForm):
    check_in = forms.DateTimeField(required=True,input_formats=['%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M','%Y-%m-%dT%H:M%Z'],widget=forms.DateTimeInput(attrs={'type':'datetime-local'}))
    check_out = forms.DateTimeField(required=True,input_formats=['%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M','%Y-%m-%dT%H:M%Z'],widget=forms.DateTimeInput(attrs={'type':'datetime-local'}))
    class Meta:
        model = Booking
        fields = ['check_in','check_out']
```

and this is my views.py , i've tried this to achieve it

```
@login_required
def add_booking(request,room_no):
   room_number = get_object_or_404(Room,room_no=room_no)
   if request.method == 'POST':
        form = BookingForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            obj = form.save(commit=False)
            if room_number.rooms.filter(check_in__gte=check_in,check_out__gte=check_out).exists():
            #if room_number.rooms.filter(Q(check_in__gte=check_in, )|Q(check_out__lte=check_out)).exists(): #but still doesnt work
                return HttpResponse('taken! sorry , try another room please')
            obj.room_no = room_number
            obj.save()  
            messages.success(request,f'room number {room_number} added')
   form = BookingForm()

   return render(request,'booking/add_booking.html',{'form':form,'room_number':room_number})
```

but doesn't work , the project is for a hotel , and booking app , i have to prevent users from selecting wrong dates ! please is it possible ?
thank you so much ..

Comment: are your `check_in` and `check_out` dates ? or date times? what do you get from user? 
if you are getting `date` obj convert it to `datetime` then filter with your `datetime` fields. it happens because you are comparing `date` with `datetime`

Comment: they are date times

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should do two separate checks for each date and I think you messed up with `gte` and `lte` parameters.

For instance `gte` checks that the value in your db is greater than or equals to the value you are passing into a filter.

You can achieve what you want by doing:

```
check_in_filter = Q(check_in__lte=check_in) & Q(check_out__gte=check_in)
check_out_filter = Q(check_in__lte=check_out) & Q(check_out_gte=check_out)
room_number.rooms.filter(check_in_filter | check_out_filter).exists()
```

Now the last expressions returns True if any date that is being selected fits into the range of existing dates.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that what is eventually needed is that if either of the `check_in` or `check_out` dates are within the existing dates, it shouldn't allow booking.

```py
check_in_within_dates = Q(check_in__lte=check_in) & Q(check_out__gte=check_in)
check_out_within_dates = Q(check_in__lte=check_out) & Q(check_out__gte=check_out)

room_numbers.rooms.filter(
    check_in_within_dates | check_out_within_dates
)
```

So, in the example scenario, it will match the first condition `check_in_within_dates` and wouldn't allow booking.

Comment: thank you , but still it accept the wrong date and times

Comment: Can you add some examples that exactly which dates etc. are failing with this approach?

Comment: `    check_in = forms.DateTimeField(required=True,input_formats=['%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M','%Y-%m-%dT%H:M%Z'],widget=forms.DateTimeInput(attrs={'type':'datetime-local'}))` it my inout formats

Comment: i've entered `3-7-2021 13:07 PM to 6-7-2021 13:07PM` after that i tried to enter `3-7-2021 12:00 PM to 4-7-2021 12:00 PM` it accepted

Comment: @HunarMohammed try the answer above, it should do the trick.

Comment: this answer does the same mistake as you do in the original question messing up `gte` and `lte` lookups.

Comment: @Gtzzy you are right. Thanks for pointing it out. Looks like I messed it up. Updated the answer.